# How to delete the history of a git commit?

Tags: git, github

I recently did an interactive rebase to remove a specific commit from my repo. However, I can still see the details of the commit by using `git show <commit hash>`. How do I entirely remove the history of this deleted commit?

I asked "How to remove the history of a commit?", Not "How to remove a commit from git history". This is not a duplicate question. None of the suggestions provide a solution to my question.

Comment: Had that commit been pushed to a remote?

Comment: `git reflog expire --all BRANCH1 BRANCH2 && git prune --expire now`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22remove+commit%22

Comment: I asked "How to remove the history of a commit?", Not "How to remove a commit from git history". This is not a duplicate question. None of the suggestions provide a solution to my question.

Comment: What do you think "history of a commit" means?  The only "history of a commit" that exists is the commit itself, and its children. Therefore, the only way to remove "the history of a commit" is to remove the commit.

Comment: @Flimzy I already removed the commit but using `git show` I can still see the details of the commit. How do I remove those details?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes

Comment: @phd Tried already. Doesn't work

Comment: That means something else (an open branch, for example) is still referencing it.

Comment: Then removing it from GitHub means a request to their support, you *can't* do it yourself. See e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository.

Comment: `git branch --contain <commit hash>`, `git tag --contain <commit hash>`

Comment: https://github.com/7Ragnarok7/DEDMAP Here's my repo if anyone wants to have a look. The hash of the commit which I am concerned about is: ab472

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, you are right. I have two tags in my master branch and using `git tag --contain <commit hash>` lists both of the tags. How do I stop these tags from referencing it? Do I have to remove those tags and create new tags again?

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the tags

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy. It fixed the issue. However the name of the person who did that commit is still showing in the github contributor's list. Is there anyway to remove it from github?

Answer (score 0):

If the commit is not in the history of any branch or tag you can do this:

```
git gc --aggressive
```

`git gc` is also run as a side-effect of some other git commands like `push` or `pull` so the commit should disappear automatically after some time.